# JNI: packaging code into self-contained binaries

Tags: java, c, jar, java-native-interface

I am currently working on a hybrid java/C project.
Because I like to reduce runtime obstacles as much as possible, I tend to integrate resources (pictures) in my binary, thus eliminating errors such as "picture not found", which might occur when the user moves my binary around.
I know that I can include java files into my C executable (via, e.g. C23 #embed or xxd). Normally, binaries amounting to several MBs are not a issue anymore on modern machines.
I can then load the classes in my C program via (a simple foreach loop at the beginning of the program):

```
jclass DefineClass(JNIEnv *env, const char *name, jobject loader,
const jbyte *buf, jsize bufLen);
```

My question is: how can I do that for whole jar files? I would like to include, e.g. the selenium API in my binary? Is it a sufficient unzip every jar file, include it in the binary, and DefineClass them?
Are there any obstacles that I might be missing?

EDIT: My entry point is on the C-Side. In fact, the whole application does not contain any Java code, it just uses some APIs from Selenium via the JNI.

Comment: When you call `defineClass`, the JVM might try to resolve references to other classes immediately, e.g. for the superclass. So you need a `ClassLoader` implementation capable of providing the class definition on demand. Calling `defineClass` for multiple classes only works if there are no circular dependencies and you know beforehand the correct order.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That could result in some ugly runtime errors.

Comment: Note well that @Holger's comment is not merely a helpful suggestion. It is the **answer**.  You need a `ClassLoader` that can load classes from your embedded binaries, and you need to get that into the application's classloader chain.  This is certainly doable, but not trivial.  Details depend to some extent on whether the application's entry point is on the Java side or the C side.

Comment: Entry point is on the C-Side

Comment: How do you ship the JVM/JRE and which version do you use?

Comment: the JVM is assumed to be preinstalled on the system, otherwise, the application can install it manually. The app works only on linux, using OpenJDK 17

Comment: Then, if you do not want to create a temporary jar file, there is no way around implementing a java class, either extending `ClassLoader` or implementing `ModuleReader`, to act as a callback to provide the classes to the JVM on demand. This Java class can be added to the JVM via `DefineClass` call then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a completely different approach, why not abuse the ZIP file format underlying JARs? ZIP files store their metadata at the end of the file, which means that you can simply append the JAR file to your binary, run an embedded JVM with the binary file added to its own classpath. Adding the entirety of selenium is then just a matter of repackaging everything into a single uberjar.

As a simple example, take Main.java:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello from java");
    }
}
```

and jni.cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    JavaVM *jvm;       /* denotes a Java VM */
    JNIEnv *env;       /* pointer to native method interface */
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args; /* JDK/JRE 6 VM initialization arguments */
    JavaVMOption* options = new JavaVMOption[1];
    std::string option = "-Djava.class.path=";
    option += argv[0];
    options[0].optionString = const_cast<char *>(option.c_str());
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = false;
    /* load and initialize a Java VM, return a JNI interface
     * pointer in env */
    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    delete[] options;
    /* invoke the Main.test method using the JNI */
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("Main");
    jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "main", "([Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    env->CallStaticVoidMethod(cls, mid);
    /* We are done. */
    jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
}
```

You can then do:

```
$ make jni
$ javac Main.java
$ jar cf code.jar Main.java
$ cat jni code.jar > jni-combined
$ ./jni-combined
Hello from java
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea, I already considered that. How does the JVM find the "JAR" in this example?

Comment: See the `"-Djava.class.path="+argv[0]` construction in `options[0]`.

Comment: Forgot to mention: You can also use this approach to store resources alongside your binary, in which case you can use libzipfile to open argv[0] and grab what you need. It's a bit more complexity in the code but I think it would simplify your build process significantly.

Comment: This would, in fact, be greatly simplified if resource forks were more common. Those are ideal for these purposes